# How to add a distortion/roughness on a Vector axis/mask?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have seperated Z-axis from vectors to mask a texture to appear only on faces (normals) facing upwards. This is working this far.

But the masking is linear and "clean". Is there a method to distort this vector "mask"? so that there is some "rough edging" or changes along the Z axis along the mask.

I hope my question makes sense. Thank you for advance.

Comment: So you are doing something like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47650/2217) and want the transition distorted. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes pretty much. I am testing the technique on a wood log which has moss on top of it. A sharp but distorted transition.

Comment: Post your node setup here so that we can see what you've already done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off of my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47650/2217) I add in a *Noise Texture* which creates the distortion.

[image: cycles material nodes]
The three selected nodes are the new ones for the distortion.

From left to right in the image below. The Z component of the normals, the Noise Texture, and the two multiplied together to make the final mask.
[image: the Fac mask and noise texture]

Comment: This is a perfect answer for my question. Thank you!